# React Amplify/Datastore- cannot get delete record to delete

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

In react, I have the following code which is running offline. I obviously found it.:

```
  async function deleteMessage() {
    toDelete = await DataStore.query(Message, c => c.id("eq","4faebf3b-f89a-4e34-978a-0fea611897e0"))
    alert("toDelete: " + !toDelete ? toDelete : toDelete.length )
    if (!toDelete || (toDelete !== undefined && toDelete.length == 0)) 
    {
      alert("Nothing to delete")
      return
    }
    alert("Deleting " + toDelete.length + " records.")
    alert("id for 0 = " + toDelete[0].id + " title: " + toDelete[0].title + " color: " + toDelete[0].color + " createdAt: " + toDelete[0].createdAt)

    await DataStore.delete(toDelete);
    alert("after delete")

   // updateFormState(initialState)
  }
```

toDelete has all the fields correct and is being displayed in the alert before the actual delete, so toDelete should be the correct model.

The one alert is saying: Deleting 1 records.

The next alert says: id for 0 = 4faebf3b-f89a-4e34-978a-0fea611897e0 title: aaasdfasdf color: #6c2f2f createdAt: undefined

But it never returns from the delete and I am getting the error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): Object is not an instance of a valid model
DataStore.<anonymous>
C:/Projects/React/src/datastore/datastore.ts:897
  894 |     sortPredicate = ModelSortPredicateCreator.createFromExisting(modelDefinition, paginationProducer.sort);
  895 | }
  896 | return {
> 897 |     limit: limit,
      | ^  898 |     page: page,
  899 |     sort: sortPredicate,
  900 | };
View compiled
```

What am I missing?

Also, the model is:

```
type Message @model {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  color: String
  createdAt: String
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Change toDelete = await DataStore.query(Message, c => c.id("eq","4faebf3b-f89a-4e34-978a-0fea611897e0"))

to

toDelete = await DataStore.query(Message, "4faebf3b-f89a-4e34-978a-0fea611897e0"))

The first example returns an array of objects.
The second example returns an object.

The DataStore.delete() expects an object not an array of objects. I was passing an array of objects.

DataStore.delete(toDelete) would work with the 2nd example but not the first since that was an object.

If I am using the first example would have to use:

DataStore.delete(toDelete[0])